# code for playing and pausing the two or more videos by scrolling using js and jq

Tags: javascript, jquery

this is working for only one video but this have to work all the videos(TWO OR MORE)

```
<html>

<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-jFdOCgY5bfpwZLi0YODkqNXQdIxKpm6y5O/fy0baSzE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie1" width="400vh" style="height:100vh;" autoplay="true" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
              </video>
    <br>
    <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie2" width="400" style="height:100vh;" autoplay="true" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>


     </video>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#video1')[0].play();
        });

        $(document).on("scroll", function() {
            if ($(document).scrollTop() > 1) {
                $('#video1')[0].pause();
            } else {
                $('#video1')[0].play();
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will pause the video once it has been scrolled up to half of its height.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function() {
  for (let i = 1; i <= $('video').length; i++) {
    if ($(`#movie${i}`).offset().top + $(`#movie${i}`).height() / 2 < $(document).scrollTop()) {
      $(`#movie${i}`).get(0).pause();
      console.log(`#movie${i} : paused`);
    } else if ($(`#movie${i}`).offset().top < $(document).scrollTop()) {
      $(`#movie${i}`).get(0).play();
      console.log(`#movie${i} : playing`);
    } else {
      $(`#movie${i}`).get(0).pause();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-jFdOCgY5bfpwZLi0YODkqNXQdIxKpm6y5O/fy0baSzE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie1" width="400vh" style="height:100vh;" autoplay="true" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
              </video>
  <br>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie2" width="400" style="height:100vh;" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  <br>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie3" width="400" style="height:100vh;" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  <br>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie4" width="400" style="height:100vh;" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
  <br>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie5" width="400" style="height:100vh;" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you. I found it while searching for the same answer myself a few months ago.

```js
var videos = document.getElementsByTagName("video"),
  fraction = 0.8;

function checkScroll() {

  for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {

    var video = videos[i];

    var x = video.offsetLeft,
      y = video.offsetTop,
      w = video.offsetWidth,
      h = video.offsetHeight,
      r = x + w, //right
      b = y + h, //bottom
      visibleX, visibleY, visible;

    visibleX = Math.max(0, Math.min(w, window.pageXOffset + window.innerWidth - x, r - window.pageXOffset));
    visibleY = Math.max(0, Math.min(h, window.pageYOffset + window.innerHeight - y, b - window.pageYOffset));

    visible = visibleX * visibleY / (w * h);

    if (visible > fraction) {
      video.play();
    } else {
      video.pause();
    }

  }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkScroll, false);
window.addEventListener('resize', checkScroll, false);
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-jFdOCgY5bfpwZLi0YODkqNXQdIxKpm6y5O/fy0baSzE=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie1" width="400vh" style="height:100vh;" autoplay="true" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
              </video>
  <br>
  <video src=" https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="movie2" width="400" style="height:100vh;" autoplay="true" controls muted>
                Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
    </video>


  </video>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this I tried its not working can I get any other solution please.

Comment: are you not trying to play the video when the user has scrolled over the video?